# Removing from set of sets in Java

Tags: java, set

I don't understand why this code prints ERROR. How can this be possible?

```
Set<Set<Place>> clusters = new HashSet<Set<Place>>();  
...         
Set<Place> max1 = null;
Set<Place> max2 = null;
double maxSim = 0;
for (Set<Place> placesSet : clusters) {
    for (Set<Place> placesSet2 : clusters) {
        if (placesSet != placesSet2) {
            double sim = calculateSim(placesSet, placesSet2);

            if (sim >= maxSim) {
                maxSim = sim;
                max1 = placesSet;
                max2 = placesSet2;
            }
        }
    }
}
if (!clusters.remove(max2)) {
    System.out.println("ERROR");
}
```

EDIT
Now I check if sim is less than 0 and clusters has more than one element. Still get ERROR

```
    Set<Place> max1 = null;
    Set<Place> max2 = null;
    double maxSim = 0;
    for(Set<Place> placesSet : clusters) {
        for(Set<Place> placesSet2 : clusters) {
            if(!placesSet.equals(placesSet2)) {
                double sim = calculateSim(placesSet, placesSet2);
                if(sim < 0) sim = 0;
                if(sim >= maxSim) {
                    maxSim = sim;
                    max1 = placesSet;
                    max2 = placesSet2;
                }
            }

        }
    }


    if(!clusters.remove(max2) && clusters.size() >= 1) {
        System.out.println("ERROR");
    }
```

NEXT EDIT:

Still ERROR :(

```
Set<Place> max1 = null;
            Set<Place> max2 = null;
            double maxSim = 0;
            for(Set<Place> placesSet : clusters) {
                for(Set<Place> placesSet2 : clusters) {
                    if(!placesSet.equals(placesSet2)) {
                        double sim = calculateSim(placesSet, placesSet2);
                        if(sim < 0) sim = 0;
                        if(sim >= maxSim) {
                            maxSim = sim;
                            max1 = placesSet;
                            max2 = placesSet2;
                        }
                    }

                }
            }


            if(max2 != null && !clusters.remove(max2) && clusters.size() > 1) {
                System.out.println("ERROR");
            }
```

Comment: @vandale - that is the answer, without a doubt.  That line can only be printed if `clusters` is empty, or contains just one element, or if `calculateSim()` returns negative every time it's called.  If you post it as an answer, I will upvote it.

Comment: calculateSim always return value >= 0. clusters has a lot of sets.

Comment: is your `max2 != null`? from javadocs `true if the set contained the specified element` which means if you passing null value and null value does not exist in clusters it might return false

Comment: You're not checking if clusters has more than 1 element. You're checking if it has more than 0.

Answer (score 3):

There appear to be two possibilities:

1. `calculateSim()` returns negative values. since `sim` will never be >= 0, your if statement will never be executed and `max2` will be null.
2. `cluster` has 0 or one element. If there are no elements, then the loop will never execute. if there is one element, the loop will execute but that element will be equal to itself so your first if will fail.

I recommend anding print statements to monitor the execution of the code

Edit: please actually insert print statements into your code:

```
       Set<Place> max1 = null;
        Set<Place> max2 = null;
        double maxSim = 0;
        System.out.printf("clusters has %d elements:%s%n",clusters.size,clusters);
        for(Set<Place> placesSet : clusters) {
            for(Set<Place> placesSet2 : clusters) {
                System.out.printf("%ncomparing %s and %s%n",placesSet,placesSet2);
                if(!placesSet.equals(placesSet2)) {
                    System.out.println("The sets are not the same");
                    double sim = calculateSim(placesSet, placesSet2);
                    System.out.printf("The sim of the sets is %f%n",sim);
                    if(sim < 0) sim = 0;
                    System.out.printf("Comparing to the max sim %f%n",maxSim);
                    if(sim >= maxSim) {
                        System.out.println("Found new max sim");
                        maxSim = sim;
                        max1 = placesSet;
                        max2 = placesSet2;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        System.out.printf("The max is %s%n",max2);

        if(max2 != null && !clusters.remove(max2) && clusters.size() > 1) {
            System.out.println("ERROR");
        }
```

Comment: @latata please run the code with print statements and check the output

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer is that all your sets of places must be the same (contain the same places). Therefore placesSet always equals placesSet2, regardless of whether they are the same actual object.

Comment: That's the same as saying that the set has just one element, as sets can't contain duplicates.  So this doesn't actually add anything that vandale's answer doesn't already cover.

Comment: Good point! Unless the Set implementation used by the inner sets overrides hashCode() in a horrible way. Unlikely, but possible.

Comment: All sets are standard java HashSets.